# may I let cygwin-bash not recognize DLLs as executable and auto-complete them

Tags: bash, cygwin, autocomplete

using GNU bash 3.2.29(20)-release from cygwin 1.5 on a windows-xp sp3 japanese installation.

being a linux user, I know in cygwin and *nix, all files with +x mod can be executable. so it is reasonable to assume all files to be (potentally) executable at first.

But in my context, there are some extension that almost never be executable , say DLLs. however, they will also be listed in bash auto-completion, which is un-nice.

so is there some way to 'mask' given file extensions so that they will not be recognized as executable file(an example , DLL again ) and appear in bash auto-complete list?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Strictly speaking, DLLs *are* executable.

Comment: @Ignacio: I'd like to see that from a Cygwin command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FIGNORE=.dll
```

It's a colon separated list:

```
FIGNORE=".foo:.bar:~"
```

Comment: it works. it takes two mes to give more gratitude.

Comment: This excludes DLLs from all filename completion though, not just when completing executable files. Can bash be tuned finer than this?